# static file not found Django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my Django app so it's a school management system that gives courses exercises and also link to live streams. but there is a problem with my app even if the file is stored in static files, it gives "file not found". I don't know what is the problem here some pics:

[image: This Images]

[image: This Images]

[image: This Images]

[image: This Images]

[image: This Images]

[image: This Images]

[image: This Images]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, see if it can help

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, 'media/image/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, 'docs/')
```